# Should we remove gemstone while sleeping? Any other situation where we should remove it?

Tags: rituals, practice, astrology

When should we remove gemstones? Should we remove them at night while sleeping? Should we remove them while having sex and bath?
I know that during funerals we should remove them, but apart from that are there other times when we should remove them?

Comment: No you should always wear them .. once you remove them you can't wear them again unless you do Sodhana (purification)

Comment: What are the asauch kriya where we should remove gems?

Comment: When u go to cremation grounds or to the houses of persons who are runnning through death/birth Asuacha .. you shd remove before going .. I can not give any scriptural references for this but this is what the astrologers ask to do

Comment: Do we consider activity of physical pleasure asauch?

Comment: Well, for that activity we do not need to remove the gemstones .. this is what I know

Comment: Also that impurity is rather shortlived... its gone as soon as one washes oneself or sips some water

Answer (score 0):

Sleeping - It's generally recommended to remove gemstone rings, bracelets, and necklaces before going to sleep. The movement of your body and sheets/blankets during sleep can cause softer gemstones like pearls, opals, turquoise, etc. to get scratched or damaged. Harder gemstones like diamonds and sapphires are less prone to scratching.

Exercise and physical activities - Remove gemstone jewelry before exercising, playing sports, doing yard work, or other strenuous physical activities. The impacts and movements can loosen gemstone settings and cause damage.

Swimming and bathing - It's best to remove gemstones before swimming or bathing. The chemicals in pools can corrode metal settings. Soap scum and water pressure can also loosen settings over time. Take them off before getting in the water.

Applying lotions/perfumes - Chemicals in lotions, creams, perfumes, hairspray, etc can build up on gemstone jewelry and affect its shine and appearance over time. Remove them before applying these products.

Cleaning - Take gemstones off before doing heavy cleaning with harsh chemicals like bleach, ammonia, and acetone. Even soapy water can get trapped behind stone settings. It's safest to remove them.

Traveling - Take gemstones off when passing through airport security. The X-ray machines and body scanners can damage some [gemstones](https://rashiratanjaipur.net/gemstones). Also, remove them when doing activities that may cause damage while traveling.

The general rule is to take gemstone jewelry off for situations involving water, chemicals, physical impact, or security. But occasional wear during lower-risk activities should be fine. Listen to your body and remove them if they ever feel too loose or uncomfortable.

Comment: These are practical consideration- the question (and this site) is more about the scriptural stipulations.